# Android cpuacct.usage file

Tags: android, file, cpu, uid

I found, in the emulator, under directory /acct/uid/10041 a file called cpuacct.usage and cpuacct.usage_percpu.
Cat on the file gave me this: *839133794*

Can some one tell me how and for what is this file used? Is it a way to limit the CPU usage for a given uid?

Thanks,
Romain

Answer (score 0):

This is a file provided by the underlying Linux kernel, which gives the CPU time (in nanoseconds) the uid has used so far.

See the [cgroups cpuacct Linux Kernel Documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups/cpuacct.txt) for more information on this.